# On the meaning of 'such' in "The historical roots of this concept extended to such non-numeric applications as legal evidence."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What similar expression could be used to replace *such* in

> The historical roots of this concept extended to **such** non-numeric applications as legal evidence.

? I've looked up some [meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/such) of *such* but wasn't able to find one that could be used as a substitute in the context above.

Source: The second bullet point under the 'Alternative views' section of [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Frequentist_probability#Alternative_views) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Wiktionary link has a definition that more or less fits under Pronoun:

> 1. A person, a thing, people, or things like the one or ones already mentioned.

The definition is a bit lacking, because the things "already mentioned" can come *after* the pronoun as in your example using the "such ... as ..." construction.

A nearly equivalent sentence written a different way is:

> The historical roots of this concept extended to non-numeric applications like legal evidence.

Wiktionary has another entry for [such as](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/such_as#English) and the following Usage Note fits here:

> In the sense of “for example”, such as is preferred to like in formal writing.

But I find that definition somewhat lacking too because it doesn't exactly cover the usage as a pronoun.